# Can you create different colors of rust on iron?

Tags: oxidation-state

I am looking to see if anyone out there can tell me if there is a way to create different colors of rust on iron. I'm specifically looking to see if I can create blue rust without heating the metal and blueing it that way. I can achieve the regular rust colors but I am looking to see if I can go beyond that. If you can help I would love the input. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Rust is a generic term for [iron oxides and hydroxides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rust), and depending on the oxidation state of the iron and the thickness of the layer, it can have [many colors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rust_on_iron.jpg). Impurities in the iron also affect the color.

By controlling the amount of air and water and by changing the composition of impure iron or steel, colors from red though blue can be achieved, though the blue may be transient if it's due to interference in a thin surface film.

That said, I know of no "recipe" to provide a given color or shade; you'd need to determine that by experiment. There are chemical treatments to change the color of iron, such as [using selenium dioxide to blue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluing_(steel)) the metal, but the result is *not* rust.

Answer (score 1):

As noted "rust" is a few different compounds.  Iron makes 3 oxides FeO ( black) Fe3 O4 ( black ) , Fe2 O3 ( red ). Rust is mostly hydrated Fe3O4 ( Brown ). Our lab did XRD on about a thousand samples for corrosion investigations; The tech matched patterns with the FINK Index as well as he could but there are various options : easiest to call rust "hydrated" Fe3O4.

Answer (score -4):

The color of rust cannot be changed. The only thing you can do is mixing with a high amount of a blue pigment, if you want to obtain a blue color with rust.

Comment: Iron oxides and hydroxides can have different colors depending on oxidation state and thickness. "Rust" is generic and denotes multiple forms.